# How to weave ( join alternating elements ) several Django QuerySets

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

How can several QuerySets be weaved in just one? I mean joining them in another QuerySet alternating their elements, without evaluating each individual QuerySet so performance is kept. For example:

```
#QuerySets to be weaved
q1 = Model.objects.filter(...)
q2 = Model.objects.filter(...)
q3 = Model.objects.filter(...)

#The QuerySet in which the previous ones are weaved
WeaveQuery = ????
```

So the first element from WeaveQuery belongs to q1, the second to q2, the third to q3, the fourth to q1... and so on. The weaved QuerySets may not have the same length, so the elements shouldn't be repeated in the WeaveQuery if one of the weaved querysets run out of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it suffices to you, to get one pass iterator of QuerySet results, you can do this:

```
# works as is in Python 3
# in Python 2.7, there are similar functions with different names
from itertools import chain, filterfalse, zip_longest
weaved = filterfalse(
    lambda x: x is None,
    chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(q1, q2, q3))
)
```

- `zip_longest` zips the querysets together, filling empty spaces (when one of them is longer than the others) with `None`
- `chain` flattens the zip, so you actually get list of results, not list of tuples of results
- `filterfalse` filters out all the `None` elements we got from `zip_longest`

The obvious flaw is, that the result is not a QuerySet, it's just an iterator of QuerySet results. But, maybe it's sufficient for you? Great thing is, that the result is iterator, nothing is evaluated prematurely, so the weave itself is blazing fast.

I'm afraid that creating real QuerySet in this way (without actually evaluating anything) would be quite difficult.